# ASP.NET MVC how to optimize hundreds images for reducing http request

Tags: image, http, optimization, request

I have a website which displays hundreds products catalog with JPEG file (File size40kb - 150kb). i realize my website generate hundreds http request. Do you have any idea how do I optimize hundreds images in asp.net MVC?

Answer (score 0):

1. embed the images on the page as Base64 encoded rather than using their URLs.  This will reduce the # of http requests the webbrowser has to make.

   http://lucdebrouwer.nl/how-to-base64-encode-your-images/
2. compress your page.

   http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

UPDATE: here is how you convert Image objects to Base64 in Asp.Net MVC

```
    private string ImageToBase64(Image image,
                                 ImageFormat format)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Convert Image to byte[]
            image.Save(ms, format);
            byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

            // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            return base64String;
        }
    }

    private Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
    {
        // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0,
                                         imageBytes.Length))
        {
            // Convert byte[] to Image
            ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
            return image;
        }
    }
```

And you use it like so:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + yourImageBase64string + '" />
```

Keep in mind doing this probably will not make your page load that much faster without compressing your page as well.  Why can't you only display a subset of these images and let the user navigate between them?

Comment: Bojin Li, could you share with me how can i convert image as Base 64 encode in ASP.NET MVC 3? my product catalog almost 200 hundreds images and customer / user can change it any time

Comment: Bojin Li, mmmmh my website is like www.amazon.com or www.sell.com i need to display all the latest products on the first page. do you have any idea how can i tuning the first page to be faster ?

Comment: I suppose you could serve the page with a few images, and then use jQuery and make ajax calls to your server for the additional images.  This way the page loads reasonably fast and the additional images will appear some time afterwards.  I think amazon does something similar to this effect.